# How does stat_summary_bin bin in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

I was wondering how does stat_summary_bin function bin when we use `bin` argument?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
               stat_summary_bin(fun='mean', bins=100,
               color='orange', size=2, geom='point') + geom_smooth(method='lm') + theme_minimal()
```

Does it split the `x-axis` into equal width? Or Does each bin have an equal number of observations?

I thought `stat_summary_bin` splits the x axis into equally spaced bins. But the following plot it the result of the above code, and it doesn't seem like it's spaced equally on the x axis.
[image: stat_summary_bin]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Seems like bins are evenly spaces but some of your bins might just be empty so no point is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code `stat_summary_bin` will make 20 bins equally spaced along the x axis. Then it will plot 1 y-axis point for each bin, based on the `mean()` for all the observations that occur within that bin.

You can observe this behaviour in the following plot

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun='mean', bins=20,
                   color='orange', size=2, geom='point')+
  geom_point()
```

Run with and without `geom_point()` turned on.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html

Comment: This is the relevant code: 1) https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-summary-bin.R  2) https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/ggplot2/src/R/stat-bin2d.r